# Rails Layout stylesheets disappearing when rendered

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

So I just started a new project and decided to go with rails for the framework. However running into a little problem with my layout stripping stylesheets when rendered:

application.html.erb:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
    <% stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <% stylesheet_link_tag "styles", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid"> <!-- Start Container -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"></nav>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid add_margin">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>XQA <small>Revolutionizing Customer Service</small></h1>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- End Container -->

    <%= yield %>

    <!-- JS After this line -->
    <% javascript_include_tag "jquery-2.1.4" %>
    <% javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.min" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

~

Server output:

```
~/Projects/QA$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-05-27 22:30:26] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-05-27 22:30:26] INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
[2015-05-27 22:30:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=13087 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-27 22:32:25 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 159ms (Views: 151.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Please point me in the right direction or logs on how I can troubleshoot this further. Thanks all!

Generated HTML Source:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>yeah</title>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="0kNM9OV6jBvQdFiUBA1PqDiIlJbkUyK0eLEllIKlguMc3+C9oq2rxiObTlH/liDmcpDENF3QEf3hYMWEqjJZ6w==" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid"> <!-- Start Container -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"></nav>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid add_margin">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>XQA <small>Revolutionizing Customer Service</small></h1>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- End Container -->



    <!-- JS After this line -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not outputting the `stylesheet_link_tag` declarations - you need to use `<%=`. `<%` will evaluate the code but not output it - `<%=` will evaluate it and output it.

eg. `<%= stylesheet_link_tag ...`

Comment: I guess that's why it works in the view but not the layout - thanks

Comment: @morissette as discussing on IRC, that code won't work in the view either. `<%` is for evaluating code only.